# Limit fixed div vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, height

I have 2-columns layout with fixed sidebar on the left and page content on the right column. I also have the footer. I want my fixed sidebar to scroll right to the coordinates of the end of the page content div.

However, if the height of sidebar is bigger than the height of page content, I need to automatically assign new height to the page content div. This code works for the first case (Content higher than sidebar), but the second case works only if I reload page one more time (when, for example, I go to this kind of page from another page, script doesn't assign new height, but when I reload page, it does)

here is the code:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
   var windw = this;
   var contentHeight = $('#content').height(); // fetch Сontent div height
   var sideHeight = $('.sidebar-nav-fixed').height(); // fetch sidebar div height
   $.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
       var $this = this,
           $window = $(windw);

       $window.scroll(function(e){
           if ($window.scrollTop() >= pos) {
               $this.css({
                   position: 'absolute',
                   top: pos
               });
           } else {
               $this.css({
                   position: 'fixed',
                   top: 100
               });
           }
       });
   };

if (sideHeight > contentHeight) {
   $('#content').css ({
   height: contentHeight + (sideHeight - contentHeight)
 }),
   contentHeight = $('#content').height() // Assign a new height to page content div
}
  $('.sidebar-nav-fixed').followTo(contentHeight - sideHeight);

});
```

I will be really glad if you have any ideas
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks  like I resolved this problem.
In my sidebar I had facebook widget which loads dynamically, so when I open the page, script fetches height without Facebook div height, as it has not loaded yet. I just made few manipulations to load scroll script after facebook widget is loaded.

Or even the better way - to put this widget into container and specify height for it manually in css.